# ldapadd child entry under alias

Tags: ldap, openldap

Suppose I have an alias entry `service=x,dc=company`. Now I wanted to add a child under this alias entry. So I run command `ldapadd ... -f a.ldif`

The content of `a.ldif` is

```
    ds=noname,service=x,dc=company
    ds: specialName
    objectClass: DsElement
```

However, I got return **`ldap_add: No such object(32)`**

What is the correct way to do that with the alias?

Answer (score 1):

You can't. It doesn't make sense. You have to add it under what the alias refers to.